# App not showing in admob when trying to link?

Tags: android, admob

Don't know if it's ok to ask this question here, but I didn't know where to ask it...

I have made an app with an ad from AdMob. It works just fine, showing up in the app and everything. The problem is when I want to link my app in the AdMob interface, my app is not showing when I search the market.

But I know that it's actually on the market because I can find it when searching on play.google.com.

[image] This is what I want to do. It says Link your app!

Anyone else had this problem and know how to fix it?

Thanks!

It is this part that I have a problem with:
[image]
At the red arrow, where it says "Find your app in the search..." My app is not showing in the search result, but I know that it is on the market!

Comment: DO you want to view statistics?

Comment: No I want to link my app, as it says in the interface. This is my first app with ads so I'm not sure what it does, and what will happen if I don't link it. But I don't like the exclamation mark. :)

Comment: Refer this- > https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?csw=1#android

Comment: The problem isn't that the ads are not showing. The problem is that when I try to link my app, as it shows in my question above, my app on the market can't be found. I can find other apps, but not my own that I want to link this ad to. Am I clear?

Comment: Okay...Then in that case you can search your app as - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.name

Comment: Yes I saw that information too, only problem is that information is regarding the "old" AdMob. I use the "new" AdMob (don't know the difference), and in the new version you cant find apps through the url, you have to search for it by name of publisher. My apps don't show up at all...

Comment: @andysando  did you fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes it fixed itself, I just had to wait aprox 24 hours before it appeared. Don't know why.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You need to wait a little bit more after publishing your app because AdMob indexes Play store and iTunes about every 48h.

Comment: Confirmed, you just really need to wait. In my case, it is now showing and ready to be "linked" after more than 2 days.

Comment: Yes, this is because indexing.

Comment: if i don't link with my app .. then it would be affect my any payment ?? @Ionut

Comment: took 4 days for me.

Comment: Well, it has been 7 days, still cannot see my app when trying to link. It is already on sale in Apple App Store.

Comment: 2-3 weeks and still waiting

Comment: @Stefan, are you getting impressions? I'm waiting for 2 weeks and I get many requests but no impressions at all.

Comment: @Daniel No, no impressions. I get requests, but they give the "No ad to show" error. I'm waiting for time to pass, so I can link my Admob app (App name -> App Settings -> Link App) with the app store app, but for now, I can't find the app...

Comment: Confirmed! Just had to wait 18 days. Once the app will appear in the "Link your app" search, it will start showing impressions. @JoeSeifi

Comment: I can also confirm. I had to wait 16 days for the app appear on admob. It happened yesterday. Ten hours after linking on admob it started getting impressions.

Comment: Released my iOS app 16 days ago. I still cannot find it in AdMob.

Comment: Is there any way to contact or raise query to AdMob? In may case its been 17 days and still its is not searchable.

Comment: This is a completely unacceptable situation from Google. Are they doing this on purpose for IOS apps? In 2021 taking weeks before they can link your app is unbelievably lame...

Comment: It has been 5 weeks and still waiting. In this tech era, shall I go to Google HQ to manually link?

Comment: Its almost 2 months now, in the App store it says "ready to for sale" is this incorrect?

Comment: my app is on App Store for more than 2 months now, and my app is only for iOS. I think Google is doing this on purpose for iOS-only apps. I think the time has come to boycott google products including Google search. its completely unacceptable situation.

Comment: @John Volkya this is July 2021, Admob takes 10 days. And I cannot find my app. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 15):

My app took 2+ days to show up in Admob. Wait, it will show up.
If your app name is a bit too common (like mine was "memes") - I would recommend to search by developer name. Admob will try to list all apps of that developer.

Comment: While you waited those 2 days, did your impression/clicks count with AdMob and you get paid or does it not count?

Comment: It's been a week & my app name still doesn't get reflect.

Comment: In my case, it took around 10 days to appear in AdMob.

Comment: Its more than 15 days and app is still not available . I raised complaints reagrding this to google but still no reply. I there any way to resolve the issue?

Comment: for me it's more than two weeks and still the app are not shown in AdMob and still no ads is showing in the app

Answer (score 5):

Instead of APP name if you provide Developer name ,then it will show of list all APPs by the developer.Then select your required APP [which was not listed when searched].
Enjoy !!!!

Comment: No, it shows my other apps but not the new one. Apparently it can take a few weeks for Google to find your IOS app in the App Store

Answer (score 5):

I've been able to resolve it today by **pasting the full AppStore URL** to that search field.

If your App is published and *available in the US region*, this should probably work. Note that it may take up to *24 hours* for the app to be visible on AppStore after releasing.

Comment: didn't work - the full url method but it helps to know to wait for 24 hrs when the caching/crawling takes place.

Comment: this worked for me. 2 days after release.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you publish the app for release. If your app is still in Beta it will not show up.

Comment: I have just seen a game that is in beta and it shows ads. Does this rule affect only apps?

Answer (score 4):

If you face issue linking your app and it takes more than 2 weeks you can contact google adMob team on google groups

Group name : [Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk)

Make sure you post your app details on the above group. My app was pending for 55 days and once I raised they have added my app in 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I have to contacted the [Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers group](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk) and they quickly fixed the issue for me. Now everything works!

**Tip**: If you didn't find your app by the name, try the following options:

- the app's AppStore URL, for example: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/spotify-discover-new-music/id324684580
- the app's store ID, for example: `id324684580`
- the publisher name, for example: `Spotify Ltd.`

Comment: Not working for me.. Tried url, app store id, developer name .. but still doesn't work.

Comment: @TarunGupta please contact the Google group first, I think they respond pretty quick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried searching using the App Name, it did not show. I also tried entering the full App store url and it did not work either. So to resolve it, I did this:

1. Went to App Store Connect -> General -> App Information -> View on App Store
2. Copied only the last 2 part of the URL `https://apps.apple.com/us/app/COPIED_THE_REST_FROM_HERE`.
3. Went to AdMob and pasted the section of the URL that looks something like this: `spotify-discover-new-music/id324684580`.

After that it worked. If the App was just released, please wait atleast 24 hours so the App listing in the store is updated.