# admob link your app

Tags: admob

, I published an android app yesterday in googleplay developer , when i am coding i add the admob code with page : Monetize a new app  => add app manualy .

Now I see an advertisement in page home of admobe (link your app)
, I am trying to link my app in admob, it says No application found. Please refine your query.

Please provide some suggestions. Should I wait more or is there any issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App not showing in admob when trying to link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733503/app-not-showing-in-admob-when-trying-to-link)

Answer (score -1):

The list of applications can be updated for a long time. (sometimes about one month)

Comment: While the application list does sometimes take a day or two to refresh, I've never heard of it needing a month.

Comment: it will never take one month! 2 days maximum