# Ads aren't showing because admob doesn't see my published app

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have published my iOS app more than 2 weeks ago and I still can't find it on AdMob, I have already tried to search it by name, developer name and app id but without success.

The problem is that production ads only display on published apps: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en
So if AdMob doesn't find my app ads will continue not to show.
I've checked my code implementation with TestAds and TestDevice and can confirm that is indeed correct.

I have already tried to contact AdMob's support but had no response, i might purchase a Google One subscription to get better mail support if i can't find no solution to this problem.

Comment: Sure, you need to connect your published app in admob. Really? Sounds like impossible. You can find every app, even not just your own one (as far as i know). Let me ask: (1) Is the published app at Google Play Store? (2) Is it your first app to connect in Admob?

Comment: Yes, actually is an iOS app so its published on the AppStore at this link: https://apps.apple.com/it/app/iregistro-diario-scuola/id1546399019 and yes its my first app

Comment: Ok, there are recent answers about this also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733503/app-not-showing-in-admob-when-trying-to-link . Someone reports it only worked after 18 days ...

Comment: So I hope its just a waiting game, thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ads showed up after 21 Days, just wait

Comment: 21 days! This is outrageous coming from Google. Are they searching for the app manually through piles of paper forms? Still waiting for mine...

Answer (score 0):

You can request your app in group:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk

You request will resolve in soon time.